# vmware tools is not working properly, I cannot share folder in my virtual machine ubuntu

Tags: windows-xp, ubuntu-11.04, vmware-player, vmware-tools

I am using windows XP, I created a virtual machine using VMware player and installed Ubuntu in it. 
I want to have a shared folder between windows and my virtual machine, so I installed VMware tools, enabled the shared folders and named them. However, when I am on ubuntu, I don't see the link... I tried several time, re-install VMware tools and updated my VMware player but it's still not working...
Does anybody already had this problem?
Versions I am using: VMware player 3.1.2, Ubuntu 11.04, VMware tools 8.4.4

Comment: Try http://superuser.com or http://askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two links that might help:

- http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/how-to-share-folders-with-your-ubuntu-virtual-machine-guest/
- http://www.sysprobs.com/install-vmware-tools-manually-ubuntu-11-04-vmware-shared-folders

Comment: I checked on your links, I did exactly what they already said, but it still look like VMware tools does not want to get installed... Guess I'll just have to wait for the next update...

Comment: I updated my VMware player and VMware tools, not it's working. But the 2 links are really good, that's exactly what I was trying to do while it wasn't working.